# Angular Material 16.1.3 - is there a **SIMPLE** way to get the "current" color and background color without custom theme?

Tags: angular-material

I'm using Angular 16.1.3 and Angular Material 16.1.3 and cannot find a **simple, straight-forward** way to retrieve whatever the current theme's color and background-color values into $ variables ***without defining a custom theme***.

So far, I have to hard-code my variables because all of the online examples and tutorials assume I want to customize the current theme.  All I want to do is pull in the "current" color and background-color values into $ variables.

So far, inside angular.json:

```
 "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

in my navigation.component.scss:

// Import theming functions
@use 'sass:map';
//FAILS: @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$background-color-active-route: #673ab7; // TODO: use $something from @angular/material "current" theme

This is where I get lost trying to read the online docs which all assume I want to customize the theme, which is not what I want to do.  I just need a simple, straight-forward way to read the ***existing*** color and background-color properties of ***whatever*** happens to be the chosen theme (deep purple amber in my specific situation).

It doesn't help that half the online examples use the now deprecated `@import` technique instead of the newer `@use` technique.  Also, I don't understand why some examples bring in `@use 'sass:map';` and some do not.